# changing the rewrite rule to subfolder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I get this code to point to a subfolder.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

previously it was www.sitename.com but now it's www.mysite.com/sitename.com

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what do you mean.

If the index.php was moved, you can change the rule like this:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sitename.com/index.php?/$1 [L]`

Or you can move the .htaccess file to the subfolder (or you can create a new .htaccess file there).

More on htaccess: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml